# Is there a builtin to access a nested yaml string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Let's say we have the following YAML structure:

```
books:
  book_one: "Some name"
  book_two: "Some other name"
```

If we load the file like:

```
f = YAML.load_file("my.yml")
```

we can access `book_one` like: `f["books"]["book_one"]`. Is there a builtin that can accept a string like: `books.book_one` and return the same value?

EDIT: This is what I have so far, and it seems to work:

```
  ...
  @yfile = YAML.load_file("my.yml")
  ...


  def strings_for(key)
    key_components = key.split(".")
    container      = @yfile
    key_components.each_with_index do |kc,idx|
      if container && container.kind_of?(Hash) && container.keys.include?(kc)
        container  = container[kc]
      else
        container = nil
      end
    end
    container
  end
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/BaseNode.html) class and the third example [here](http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/parsing_yaml_documents.htm).

Comment: Btw, you can do a bit better with `inject` - [gist](https://gist.github.com/9b3955823fbca9185833). That's what I use in one of the projects.

Comment: Have you looked at `YPath` methods in `YAML`? I looks like a powerful thing, but I doubt I'll switch to it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) and a recursive function for that for that, it would look like this:

```
require 'ostruct'

def deep_open_struct(hash)
  internal_hashes = {}
  hash.each do |key,value|
    if value.kind_of?( Hash )
      internal_hashes[key] = value
    end
  end
  if internal_hashes.empty?
    OpenStruct.new(hash)
  else
    duplicate = hash.dup
    internal_hashes.each do |key,value|
      duplicate[key] = deep_open_struct(value)
    end
    OpenStruct.new(duplicate)
  end
end

f = YAML.load_file('my.yml')
struct = deep_open_struct(f)
puts struct.books.book_one
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my extensions library:

```
class OpenStruct
  def self.new_recursive(hash)
    pairs = hash.map do |key, value|
      new_value = value.is_a?(Hash) ? new_recursive(value) : value
      [key, new_value]
    end
    new(Hash[pairs])
  end
end
```

In action:

```
struct = OpenStruct.new_recursive(:a => 1, :b => {:c => 3})
struct.a #=> 1
struct.b.c #=> 3
```

Comment: Note bad :-) Would be nice if it also turned arrays of hashes into arrays of `OpenStruct`s, which is useful for parsing YAML. I just added that as `Hash#to_ostruct` in my extension library.